# Is it possible to include custom attributes in Sandcastle documentation?

Tags: c#, sandcastle

Is it possible to include custom attributes in Sandcastle documentation?

For example, consider this c# method:

```
public void ExampleMethod
(
   [Required] string input1,
   [DefaultValue("example")] string input2
)
```

Is there any way to make Sandcastle documentation output that input1 has the required attribute?

Answer (score 0):

This works for attributes and classes, I haven't tried it on properties and fields yet. The description suggests it should work.

It might be required to turn on "Internal members" on too.

[image: Sandcastle visibility settings]
Unfortunately the documented attributes are not linked.